# Creating a hasMany Relation in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create a Tag/Content structure. A content object is assigned to a Tag object and Tag objects can be assigned to many Contents. I'm getting an error:

Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: D:\laragon\www\project1\resources\views\contents\show.blade.php)

These are my Models:

Content:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Content extends Model {
    public function tag() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Tag');
    }
}
```

Tag:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tag extends Model {
    public function contents() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Content');
    }
}
```

ContentController:

```
/**
* Display the specified resource.
*
* @param  int  $id
* @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
*/
public function show($id) {
    $content = Content::find($id);
    return View('contents.show')
                ->with('content', $content);
}
```

show.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <h1> {{ $content->tag->name }} - {{ $content->title }} </h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            Title: {{ $content->title }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            Body: {{ $content->body }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            Tag: {{ $content->tag }}
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            {!! link_to('contents', 'Back', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

The error I'm getting is from h1 tag: {{ $content->tag->name }}

Any Ideas? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: before you return view, try to return your `$content->tag` first and see what you get

Comment: Change your column name `tag` to `tag_id` and change `return $this->belongsTo('App\Tag');` to `return $this->belongsTo('App\Tag','tag_id');`

Comment: Thanks so much, that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution:

Change column name tag to tag_id and change return $this->belongsTo('App\Tag'); to return $this->belongsTo('App\Tag','tag_id');

The final code was:

Content Model:

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Content extends Model {
    public function tag() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Tag','tag_id');
    }
}
```

Tag Model:

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tag extends Model {
    public function contents() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Content');
    }
}
```

Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the table name inside model

```
protected $table ="<table_name>"
```

Comment: Getting: Cannot redeclare non static Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::$table as static App\Tag::$table

Answer (score 0):

You have to check `"$content->tag"` is valid before call `"$content->tag->name"`.

Comment: With $content->tag I only get the id of the tag

Comment: I think the problem in your table. post your tag table structure please

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in the table contents should have tag_id, but you can solve it in this way in the Content model

```
class Content extends Model {
    public function tag() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Tag');
    }
}

class Tag extends Model {
    public function contents() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Content',  'tag');
    }
}
```

Comment: Changed to return $this->belongsTo('App\Tag', 'tag'); and still same issue

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake this is how it should be

Comment: Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: D:\laragon\www\project1\resources\views\contents\show.blade.php)

Comment: <h1> <?php echo e($content->tag->name); ?> - <?php echo e($content->title); ?> </h1>

Comment: Didn't understand with "place the models" I feel I'm missing a step after changing the models.

Comment: Write the models as I wrote them and you should work

Comment: `<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Content extends Model {

    public function tag() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Tag');
    }

}`

Comment: `<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tag extends Model {

    public function contents() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Content', 'tag');
    }

}
`

Comment: no, same error: Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: D:\laragon\www\project1\resources\views\contents\show.blade.php)